# Closing a GUI window from the command line

Tags: command-line, gui, cinnamon

I often run scripts to transform a CSV file which I then preview in LibreOffice.  I often open the CSV with `xdg-open file.csv`.  However, if I run that command when the file is already open, LibreOffice simply focuses that window - it doesn't reload the file from disk.

Is there a way, from the command line, that I can specify a window to close in the GUI?  I can't just kill the process, since LibreOffice shares a single pid for all its windows.  I'm running the latest version of Cinnamon on Mint 17.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use xkill, xdotool or wmctl.

type xkill on the terminal and then click on the window you want to close.

Comment: I suggest you explain **how** to achieve the goal with these tools.

Comment: type xkill on the terminal and then click on the window you want to close.

Comment: You should put this explanation into your answer.

Comment: Based on this, I found xdotool meets my needs: `xdotool search "$FILENAME" windowactivate --sync key --window 0 --clearmodifiers alt+F4.

Comment: xkill will kill the process (not just close the program).

Answer (score 1):

`xkill` works if you actually want to kill the application, but if you only want to close the window, `xdo` or `xdotool` are better.

My use case is to close/show Transmission's window. Transmission runs a daemon, and `xkill` also kills the daemon. But I only want to close the window, not kill the entire application.

`xdotool` has a `windowclose` action, which could be used with something like:
`xdotool search "Transmission" windowclose`

However, this doesn't work for some reason. Both `xdotool` and `xdo` find multiple windows for "Transmission" (same amount whether a window is shown or not), maybe that's causing issues for `xdotool`.

But `xdo` worked for me:
`xdo close -a "Transmission"`